# Error response from daemon - scrapinghub/splash

Tags: docker, web-scraping, scrapy, daemon, scrapy-splash

I have installed scrapy-splash and docker toolbox for windows7, in order to be able to scrape data from websites using javascript. Installation seems to be fine since all the checks are giving expected results. Docker has successfully pulled `scrapinghub/splash` but when I am running it using `docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash` I am getting the below error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint zen_elion (f9c8f17e6e7413908721ddfabe294a5aa7b390e326972cac6a89afd8f0853356): Bind for 0.0.0.0:8050 failed: port is already allocated.

How do I go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line:

`run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash`

change the first port to something different, that you know is an available port on your machine. for example if you **know** port `8060` is free, then:

`run -p 8060:8050 scrapinghub/splash`

There are many ways/software to see which ports are currently in use, one that I like to use is: [TMX](https://www.mitec.cz/tmx.html)

It has a Network tab that shows ports:

[image]